# Adobe Flash Canvas updated images keep exporting as the old image anyway

Tags: flash, html5, canvas

Is there some hidden image caching in Flash HTML5 Canvas?  I updated an image in the library, the updated image showed on the stage. I deleted the old image from the asset folder it was imported from, and cleared my browser cache so ostensibly the old image does not exist anymore. But flash canvas keeps exporting the old image instead of the updated version of the image. Is this a known glitch in the software?

I actually could not get the software to export my updated image that was showing up on the stage. I just had to change that image in the export image folder to the updated one, and then not publish 'images' again, otherwise it would just continue to save the old image (that no longer exists anywhere) over my new one.

Adobe, can you start caring about your software again and making it great? Right now a lot of it's super buggy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't help you with a hard and fast solution. Instead, I would like to add to the discussion the experiences I've been having with JS export from Flash CC2015.

I made sure the PNGs that went into Flash were sRGB for best colour compatibility between browsers. I made sure to specify in the image property in Flash to use the original image upon export. Result: Flash changed the colour space of the images when exporting.

Now I deal with an agency that does not want images in subfolders. But Flash does not allow not specifying a subfolder. So I export once, drag the images out of the "images" (default name) folder and erase the directory in the JS manually. Result: The images show in the animation, but at a different scale and different placement (with a different anchor).

Apparently the only remedy to all of these issues is: Turn off image export in Flash and MANUALLY paste the original images (pre-Flash) into your output folder. Every. Single. Time.